# How can you copy a vector to vector with pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I can't seem to find a good answer to this but I am currently trying to copy the first 10 values of a vector into another vector but it is a char*. Here is my current relevant code:

```
vector<char> letters {.... many letters}
vector<char*> evenMoreLetters;
evenMoreLetters.reserve(5)

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    evenMoreLetters.push_back(&letters[i]);
}

//Code used to output evenMoreLetters
for(int i= 0; i < evenMoreLetters.size(); i++)
{
  std::cout << evenMoreLetters[i];
}
cout << "\n";
```

Comment: The problem is when outputting a bunch of garbage comes out.

Comment: Are these pointers meant to be copied as pointers, or did you try to copy the memory they're pointing to? Of course a vector can contain pointers, and these c an be copied. Post a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 3):

`operator<<` has an overload for `char*`, but it requires the `char*` to be a pointer to a **null-terminated string**. Your `char*` pointers are not pointing at null-terminated strings, hence the random garbage you are seeing.  Your code has *undefined behavior*  from reading into surrounding memory.

If you want to print out the single characters being pointed at, you need to dereference the pointers so you call the `operator<<` overload for `char` instead, eg:

```cpp
std::cout << *(evenMoreLetters[i]);
```

Otherwise, use `cout.write()` instead:

```cpp
std::cout.write(evenMoreLetters[i], 1);
```